# Windows Phone 8 WebView doesn't load Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8, webview, visual-studio-2013

I just created a simple Visual Studio 2013 project with the "WebView-App" template for Windows Phone 8.0, which loads an external URL of a specific website.
The websites HTML includes Javascript files, which are not being loaded within the App.

It looks like Javascript is disabled on default. I tried to set IsJavascriptEnabled=true within the XAML file, but it didn't work.

Might be a stupid and simple question, sorry, but I wasn't able to find any solution for this by now.

Niko

Comment: The correct syntax is IsScriptEnabled="True". Did you try it?

Comment: Can you share the URL and any additional information?

Comment: None of the tested URLs with JavaScript really work. But mine is www.paeschke.de

Comment: I create a test app with single page with WebBroser control:<phone:WebBrowser Source="http://www.paeschke.de/" IsScriptEnabled="True" Name="webBrowser"/> Everything works just fine. Maybe you miss something?

Comment: If you are talking about Windows Phone 8.1 when there might be problems with javascript. You can try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn715902.aspx

Comment: As i see in Windows Phone 8.1 when i press menu button on top of the page there is exception: SCRIPT5007: Unhandled exception at line 80, column 23 in http://www.paeschke.de/site/assets/aiom/js_b018b966b2d156b91ec2e3835ece44ad.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'application/x-shockwave-flash' of undefined or null reference
File: js_b018b966b2d156b91ec2e3835ece44ad.js, Line: 80, Column: 23

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unhandled exception at line 80, column 23 in http://www.paeschke.de/site/assets/aiom/js_b018b966b2d156b91ec2e3835ece44ad.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'application/x-shockwave-flash' of undefined or null reference
File: js_b018b966b2d156b91ec2e3835ece44ad.js, Line: 80, Column: 23

Comment: It was indeed a simple JavaScript-Error that made the whole WebView just stop. Thanks for your help and sorry for the very late reply.